# Adonis.js Relationships

Tags: node.js, orm, adonis.js

I have these tables: *companies, branches, users, users_branches*

Every **branch** is linked to a **company**. The user can be linked to a branch that captures in the **users_branches** pivot table

In the index and show methods of the **company** I need to display only as companies that the user has access to, that is, only as companies that are linked to any branch that he is registered with. Can you help me?

What I have today is this, very basic and listing everything:

```
async index () {
  const companies = await Company.all()
  return companies
}

async show ({ params }) {
  const company = await Company.findOrFail(params.id)

  await company.load('branches')

  return company
}
```

I've tried to do it in two other ways:

```
async index ({ auth }) {
  const { user } = auth

  return user.branches().company().fetch()
}
```

and

```
async index () {
  const companies = await Company.query()
    .whereHas('branches', branchesQuery => {
      branchesQuery.wherePivot('user_id', 1)
    })
    .fetch()

  return companies
}
```

But it does not work

Answer (score 0):

This might work, (you may also need to change `'user_id'` to `'id'` if it gives any error, also enable DEBUG and watch the query

```js
const companies = await Company.query()
.whereHas('branches', branchesQuery => {
  branchesQuery.whereHas('users', uq => {
    uq.where('user_id', 1)
  })
})
.fetch()
```